# RoR- erb file added text is Garbled

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added text "hello world" in erb file and ran it.
It will be garbled in front of text.

Thanks for help!!
[image: garbled]

[image]

Comment: Please provide the actual code of yours, else we can't really help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to save the ERB file as a Rich Text Format file. Try saving it as a "plain text" file.